# How to retrieve Sentinel-1 data with specifying orbit direction (ascending or descending) using OpenEO

Tags: api, sentinel-1, copernicus, sar

I am using Python's API for OpenEO. This is the code I have for the datacube:

```
sentinel1_cube = con.load_collection(
"SENTINEL1_GRD",
spatial_extent={"west": 21.60, "south": 56.20, "east": 22.00, "north": 56.40},
temporal_extent=["2021-07-01", "2021-07-30"],
bands=["VV", "VH"],)
```

I assume that it retrieves both ascending and descending orbits of the Sentinel-1 satellite. However, I need to retrieve them separately by specifying direction either ascending or descending. I could not find any cube dimension that states the orbit direction. Is there any way to retrieve data by orbit type?